# How to instantiate a scipy Delaunay triangulation from vertices and simplices

Tags: scipy, scipy-spatial

Given a list of vertices and simplices, I would like to instantiate a `scipy.spatial.Delaunay` object such that I can use its `Delaunay.find_simplex` method on my triangulation. I did not find any way to do so. The only option I found is to to instantiate the object from the vertices only but this approach:

1. does not preserve my original simplices
2. it seems unnecessary slow as it has to recompute the triangulation.

I would expect the Delaunay class to implement a class method:

```
class scipy.spatial.Delaunay:

    @classmethod
    def from_vertices_and_simplices(cls, vertices, simplices):
        ...
```

that allows me to instantiate a triangulation from its vertices and simplices such that I can do

```
triangulation = scipy.spatial.Delaunay.from_vertices_and_simplices(vertices=vertices, simplices=simplices)
simplex_index = triangulation.find_simplex(point_to_locate)
```

Any thought?

Answer (score 1):

`scipy.spatial.Delaunay` is a Delaunay triangulation that is based on the [Qhull library](http://www.qhull.org/). It computes the Delaunay triangulation by computing the (n+1 dimensional) convex hull of the points lifted to a paraboloid (see, for example, in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation#d-dimensional_Delaunay) or slide 16 of [this presentation](https://csaws.cs.technion.ac.il/%7Ebarequet/teaching/cg/fa16/CG-lecture10-DT.pdf), or [other](https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/%7Esuri/cs235/Lifting.pdf) web references on the lifting algorithm).
This means that it's algorithms depend on its inner qhull representation and data-structures and a construction from vertices-and-simplices isn't sufficient.

Therefore, in order to use its `find_simplex` method you have no choice but to reconstruct the Delaunay triangulation from the vertices you have.

As for 1 in your question, the fact that the constructed simplices do not preserve your initial simplices may indicate that your initial triangulation was not a Delaunay or that it is a degenerate (or near-degenerate) point configuration (since Delaunay triangulations are unique up to degenerate configurations).
Another possibility is that it just doesn't preserve the *order* of your simplices, in which case you can map the simplex-tuples between your ordering and the constructed one (assuming you preserved the ordering of the initial vertices).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Alternatively would there be a way to save/serialize the state of the Delaunay object (or the Qhull) to load/deserialize it later without having to have to recompute the triangulation. Something like `bytes = my_delaunay.to_bytes()` and `my_delaunay = scipy.spatial.Delaunay.from_bytes(bytes)`

Comment: `pickle.dump` and `pickle.load` should work